# Which mysql driver will suport ejabberd 2.1.13 perfectly?

Tags: mysql, erlang, xmpp, ejabberd

I want to configure Ejabberd with Mysql. I have seen many mysql drivers available in different sites. I don't know which will work fine with ejabberd 2.1.13. 
I am using drivers from the link -
https://github.com/dizzyd/erlang-mysql-driver

And these are not working fine.

Comment: What do you mean by not working fine? Are you facing any errors, exceptions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use https://svn.process-one.net/ejabberd-modules/mysql/trunk/

This is a deprecated repository, but will work with 2.1.x.